# JavaFX: Play a sound when ever something is clicked

Tags: java, audio, javafx

I currently have my EventHandler here:

```
theScene.setOnMouseClicked(
            new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
                    if (targetData.containsPoint(e.getX(), e.getY())) {
                        double x = 50 + 400 * Math.random();
                        double y = 50 + 400 * Math.random();
                        targetData.setCenter(x, y);
                        mediaPlayer.play(); //play hitsound
                        points.value++; //add points
                    } else {
                        points.value = 0; //miss
                    }
                }
            });
```

I also have my audio setup like so:

```
    String hitNormal = ("hit.mp3");
    Media sound = new Media(new File(hitNormal).toURI().toString());
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(sound);
```

When I run my program, only the first click on the circle plays the hitsound, but all the following circles do not play the sound. I think what I have above should work since every time I click additional circles it always adds score. Since I have my mediaPlayer.play(); in the exact same if statement as the line that adds score, I expected the sound to play as well. How do I get my hitsound to play every time I click the circle?

EDIT: I added mediaPlayer.stop(); under points.value++ and it seems to occasionally play the hitsound but not always.

Comment: Have you tried using `mediaPlayer.pause()` at all?

Comment: I don't think theres a need for pausing the 1 second audio clip.
Can you explain more on where I can use mediaPlayer.pause(); ?

Comment: Sorry nevermind that, I misunderstood the method.

Comment: Just guessing: perhaps it is not properly reaching the end of the media from the previous time it is played (for some reason). Try `mediaPlayer.seek(Duration.ZERO);` immediately before `mediaPlayer.play();`.

Comment: I tried that. Thank you, works like a charm!
Is there a way I can mark your comment as a correct answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the question comments you mention the audio is only a second long. If that's the case using an `AudioClip` might be better suited for your needs than `Media`/`MediaPlayer`.

An `AudioClip` can be played more than once in parallel (allowing multiple quick hits to play the sound at once) unlike a `MediaPlayer`. It also can be played as many times as you want without much hassle.

If you stick with a `MediaPlayer` James_D and TomN seem to be on the right track. From some little testing it seems a `MediaPlayer`, after reaching the end the media, doesn't simply restart when you call `play()`. The reason for this is because the `Status` of the `MediaPlayer` doesn't change from `PLAYING` to `STOPPED` when the media is finished. And since `play()` does nothing when the `Status` is `PLAYING` it won't restart.

To get around this you have to first set the time to 0 by using `seek(Duration.ZERO)` and then call `play()`. In fact, after the first time, calling `play()` doesn't seem necessary if you haven't called `pause()` or `stop()` anywhere before.

However, since your audio is only a second long I still recommend `AudioClip`. The class is designed for exactly what you're doing from what I can tell.

Comment: I tried `AudioClip`. Using `AudioClip` works better than using `seek(Duration.ZERO)`  since I can feel a small delay when using `seek(Duration.ZERO)`.
 Thank you for expanding on the solution!

Answer (score 0):

You properly need to check the status of media player, this method may helps `mediaPlayer.getStatus()`.

when it's playing, another `play()` method seem to do nothing because it change status to playing but it already does. see [MediaPlayer](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.html#play()) and [MediaPlayer.Status](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.Status.html)

---

try use below method in your code.

`mediaPlayer.stop()` it will stop the media and reset current time to zero.

add this method when media is end. you can try as below code

```
mediaPlayer.setOnEndOfMedia(new Runnable() 
{
    public void run() 
    {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
    }
});
```

or use `mediaPlayer.seek()` seek current time.

when previous media isn't yet to reach end, you need to pause it and seek current time to zero before next `play()`.